Correct way to compare results of binary classifiers with different sensitivities
I am comparing 5 third party classification models on a subset of results (specifically, false positives I am examining to find a common cause). The five models all output values between 0 and 1 but seem to have different overall sensitivities.
I could try and calculate a skew value for each model's distribution from the entire dataset to normalise it, or I could normalise the classification only within the range of outputs associated with the subset values. (Note that this is a heavily uneven dataset.)

Hi, Jess! If the outputs are between 0 and 1, then they are not making classifications. How do you get classifications from those raw outputs? There is a default method (despite its flaws), there are alternative methods (which also have flaws), and then there is a school of thought that the raw outputs should be assessed without making any classifications.

@Dave thanks for your reply, so the approach I used so far was to calculate the optimum threshold by calculating F1 along the precision-recall curve to turn a "probability" output into a class

You should try doing Probability Calibration. Training a model is much like optimizing a transformation:
\begin{align} 
f: X\rightarrow\hat{p}
\end{align}
Where X is an input vector and p̂ are the predicted probabilities (e.g. [0.20, 0.8] in a binary classification problem). But the thing is p̂ only acts as an actual probability when your model is well-calibrated.
Let's say you have pictures of cats and dogs (0 for cats and 1 for dogs) and let's also create prediction bins for different probabilities: [0.0, 0.33, 0.67, 1.0]. For a well-calibrated model, you'd expect to find 100% pictures of cats in the [0.0] bin and the same for dogs in the [1.0] bin. For the [0.33] bin, you'd expected to find 2/3 of cats and 1/3 dogs and the other way around for the [0.67] bin. If you were to find, say 9/10 cats and 1/10 dogs in the [0.33] bin then it would mean that your model is poorly calibrated.
You'll probably find a clearer explanation of it on YouTube. Overall I'd say thay you should definitely check the models's calibration curves before calibration, see if they improve after calibration and then use a binary metric of your choice (AUC, F1, etc.) to evaluate their generalization.
